# I have always been or I always was

Tags: tense

Could you explain me which is the correct answer:

I'm 19 and I'm quite shy. I _____ (always was/have always been) like that since I remember and probably would still be if I hadn't met Rebecca.....

Comment: By the way, were these options already provided or did you give them for our convenience?

Comment: They were provided

Answer (score 1):

These examples should help:

> *I have been* playing football for the last 10 years.

means, that I started playing football 10 years ago and I'm still continuing this activity up until now.

---

> *I was* asking this question yesterday.

means, that action happened in a particular frame of time, and it has finished.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm 19 and I'm quite shy. I **had always been** like that since I remember and probably would still be if I hadn't met Rebecca...

*"had been"* is the most correct one, though it is not included in the options. It appears like you are writing a story or something similar, and I think the sentence I wrote above will be the best fit.

***Had Been*** denotes an action which was continuing for a long period of time (in your case, shyness), but it is over now.

However, if you want answers among the two options mentioned, "have always been" would be the correct one.

***Have Been*** denotes an action which started in the past, but is still ongoing. This would be the perfect match for your sentence, if chosen between the two options.

For more reference: [Had been Vs Have been](https://www.gonaturalenglish.com/the-difference-between-i-have-been-and-i-had-been/)

Answer (score 0):

"have always been", because it is a continuous tense, it will really match with your sentence.

Comment: Please explain why it matches better than the other option; we want to teach people, not just give them an answer without reasons. You could [edit] your answer to make it better.